# Open video in own window inside the original window

Tags: html, css

The question can sound confusing, so this images describes it much better: 
https://ibb.co/cVSQEv

The pop-up window should appear when clicking on an image, is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [**FancyBox**](http://fancybox.net/) or similar scripts.